# when i wanna parse a html page, why xpath query return null?

Tags: xpath

I wanna parse an HTML page, that has a next page button. button title is tt. I wanna get button id for next page number. my code is:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($response);

$xpath = new \DOMXpath($dom);

$ne = $xpath->query('//a[@class="btn chang-page" and @title="tt"]/@id');

   while ($ne->length > 0) 

        {

        // go to next page and parse nodes in it.
        // $response=nextpage();

         $dom = new \DOMDocument;

         @$dom->loadHTML($response);

         $xpath = new \DOMXpath($dom);

         $ne = $xpath->query('//a[@class="btn chang-page" and @title="tt"]/@id');

    }
```

this code just works for page one and page two. for page 3 return null. why?

Comment: You need to provide the HTML if anyone is going to be able to give you a definite answer. However, at a guess, page 3 is the last page.